# calculate the percentage of times the highest value of a row corresponds in each variable

Tags: r, dataframe, row, percentage

I have a data frame in R as follows:

```
set.seed(123)
    A <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20 * 5, mean = 0, sd = 1), 20, 5))
```

which results in:

```
> A
            V1          V2          V3          V4           V5
1  -0.56047565 -1.06782371 -0.69470698  0.37963948  0.005764186
2  -0.23017749 -0.21797491 -0.20791728 -0.50232345  0.385280401
3   1.55870831 -1.02600445 -1.26539635 -0.33320738 -0.370660032
4   0.07050839 -0.72889123  2.16895597 -1.01857538  0.644376549
5   0.12928774 -0.62503927  1.20796200 -1.07179123 -0.220486562
6   1.71506499 -1.68669331 -1.12310858  0.30352864  0.331781964
7   0.46091621  0.83778704 -0.40288484  0.44820978  1.096839013
8  -1.26506123  0.15337312 -0.46665535  0.05300423  0.435181491
9  -0.68685285 -1.13813694  0.77996512  0.92226747 -0.325931586
10 -0.44566197  1.25381492 -0.08336907  2.05008469  1.148807618
11  1.22408180  0.42646422  0.25331851 -0.49103117  0.993503856
12  0.35981383 -0.29507148 -0.02854676 -2.30916888  0.548396960
13  0.40077145  0.89512566 -0.04287046  1.00573852  0.238731735
14  0.11068272  0.87813349  1.36860228 -0.70920076 -0.627906076
15 -0.55584113  0.82158108 -0.22577099 -0.68800862  1.360652449
16  1.78691314  0.68864025  1.51647060  1.02557137 -0.600259587
17  0.49785048  0.55391765 -1.54875280 -0.28477301  2.187332993
18 -1.96661716 -0.06191171  0.58461375 -1.22071771  1.532610626
19  0.70135590 -0.30596266  0.12385424  0.18130348 -0.235700359
20 -0.47279141 -0.38047100  0.21594157 -0.13889136 -1.026420900
```

I want to find in each row the location of the highest value and display the percentage of times that the highest value was in the specific column. i.e.,

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
2%  25% 40% 30% 3%
```

How can I calculate this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max.col` and `table`:

```r
max.col(A)
#  [1] 4 5 1 3 3 1 5 5 4 4 1 5 4 3 5 1 5 5 1 3
table(max.col(A))
# 1 3 4 5 
# 5 4 4 7 
table(names(A)[max.col(A)])/nrow(A)
#   V1   V3   V4   V5 
# 0.25 0.20 0.20 0.35
```

Though this doesn't match your expected output, I suspect that that's because you were just demonstrating what it would look like ...

Answer (score 2):

Similar to r2evans's solution, but filling in the 0s:

```
max.col(A) |> 
  factor(levels = seq_along(A), labels = names(A)) |>
  table() |> 
  prop.table()
#   V1   V2   V3   V4   V5 
# 0.25 0.00 0.20 0.20 0.35
```

Comment: I like the inclusion of empty columns

Comment: I like your `max.col`---I was about to post my `apply(1, which.max)` answer when I saw yours post ;)

Comment: thank you. Both answers works perfectly. I will accept @r2evans because he replied first.